# What is the cause of "Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined" in a node.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to form a URL by joining different elements. I am getting

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined.

When I am running the following code. Any suggestion is much appreciated!

```
...
function joinUrlElements() {
    "use strict";
    var re1 = new RegExp('^\\/|\\/$', 'g'),
        elts = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    return elts.map(function (element) {
        return element.replace(re1, "");
    }).join('/');
}
....
```

Comment: It means that one of the elements in `elts` is `undefined`. You cannot access properties on `undefined`. Since you are not showing how `joinUrlElements` is called and what arguments you pass to it, that's all we can really say about it.

Comment: Could be a number too

Comment: What parameters are passed to `joinUrlElements()` call? Can you create a stacksnippets to demonstrate? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @mplungjan: Then it would say "undefined is not a function".

Comment: But would also fail :)

Comment: @mplungjan: As Suren said, with a different error message. The question is what causes this particular error. Of course JavaScript can fail for all sorts of obscure reasons ;)

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post the code which calls this function. Maybe seeing how it is called will be easier for everyone to figure this one out.

Comment: `joinUrlElements(undefined)` or `var data; joinUrlElements(data)` would reproduce issue, though we should not have to speculate as to what the actual code used is.

Answer (score 1):

This means that your `elts` has a item, which value is set to `undefined`.

Also with `ES6` you ca use [**rest parameters**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) which will replace using `arguments` variable in your case.

See an example

```js
function joinUrlElements(...args) {
    var re1 = new RegExp('^\\/|\\/$', 'g');

    return args.map(function (element) {
        return element.replace(re1, "");
    }).join('/');
}

console.log(joinUrlElements('first', 'second', 'third'));
```

Comment: A number also fails: `console.log(joinUrlElements('first', 'second', 3, 'fourth'));`

Comment: Yes, but with another error. `element.replace is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

One of the arguments when you are calling this function causes an element of the array to be "undefined" and when map tries to operate on this item it throws the error.

Comment: No. If that was the case `elts` would simply be empty, i.e. the callback pass to `.map` would never be executed.

Comment: mmm, not sure how your comment can help/dismiss my answer, can you please explain why "No............."

Comment: Anyways, calling ```Array.prototype.slice.call();``` on null or undefined, doesnt get you an empty array, it throws an error.

Comment: Sure, but `arguments` is never `null` or `undefined`.